# Python XML sports players

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to print the first name, last name, proteam, and the headline for each player in this XML http://api.cbssports.com/fantasy/players/list?version=3.0&SPORT=basketball

This is my code so far but it isn't working

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

request = Request('http://api.cbssports.com/fantasy/players/list?version=3.0&SPORT=basketball')

try:
   response = urlopen(request)
   tree = ET.parse(response)
   root = tree.getroot()
   for player in root.findall('.//players'):
      firstname = player.find('firstname').text
      lastname = player.find('lastname').text
      print firstname, lastname
except URLError, e:
    print 'error:', e
```

I believe the error is in the for loop statement because firstname is not a direct child of players, its parent is player id

Comment: How is it you knew how to do the right thing with `players` but not `firstname` and `lastname`?

Comment: Im very new to this haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend a double slash to search anywhere inside the context, current element. And you need to iterate over `player` elements instead of `players`:

```
for player in root.findall('.//players/player'):
    firstname = player.findtext('.//firstname')
    lastname = player.findtext('.//lastname')
```

Comment: Okay I did this but it only printed the first player. It took a while so it must have been gathering all the players not sure why it didn't print them

Comment: Thanks. How would I add in the headline though since its parent is icons?